# On OpenShift next-gen, how to specify a Wildfly datasource?

Tags: openshift, postgresql-9.5, wildfly-10

On next-gen OpenShift, how do I get wildfly to use PostgreSQL as my datasource?

I've tried setting the environment variables in the wildfly pod so it matches up with the standalone.xml, but that doesn't work as my WAR complains it was unable to locate the PostgreSQL datasource

Comment: Have you downloaded and read through the free OpenShift book at https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html This covers Wildly and PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know you guys had an updated book for free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself. You need to update the following environment variables for PostgreSQL on OpenShift Online:

- POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=sampledb
- POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_PORT=5432
- POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_HOST=172.11.22.33
- POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=wildfly
- POSTGRESQL_USER=wildfly
- POSTGRESQL_DATASOURCE=PostgreSQLDS

If you rsh into your wildfly pod, take a look at `/wildfly/bin/standalone.conf` to see how the other environment variables are set up for other databases.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you set these 3 env vars at your OpenShift Console / Your Project / Applications / Deployment / Your Deployment (despesas in my case) / Environment:

[image: Deployment / Environment]